# How to print space in uint64_t (C)

Tags: c, printf, uint64

When I try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  uint64_t key = 0xf0000000ffffffff;

  printf ("key=%" PRIx64, key, "\t\n  %" PRIx64, "\n", key);
}
```

It prints `key=f0000000ffffffff`; all whitespaces are removed. How can I print them? I am using `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3`.

Comment: Never ignore the compiler warnings ... such as `too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]` for a decent gcc

Comment: There was no warning. Neither I suppressed it. @fritzone

Comment: @fritzone `gcc`. I stated it in my question. My OS is `Mint Olivia Xfce (64 bit)`.

Comment: yup, saw it too late :) Removed the comment. gcc 4.7.3 is actually a pretty decent compiler, it should have given a warning ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format string you provide to [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is only

```
"key=%" PRIx64
```

All the rest are arguments for the format string, ans since the format string only contain one conversion specifier the first argument is printed and the rest are discarded.

I think you want e.g.

```
printf("key=%" PRIx64 "\t\n  %" PRIx64 "\n", key, key);
```

Note the lack of commas in the format string.